# Question about the following vector belongs to the range space of the linear operator or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, matrices, definite-integrals, linear-transformations

Let $f_1(t), f_2(t), f_3(t), f_4(t)$ be the given continuous functions, $\mathbf{B}_1 \&  \mathbf{B}_2$ are the given $2\times 1$ constant matrices, $\mathbf{A}$ is $2\times 2$ given constant matrix.

If $\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies the following equation for certain functions $\mathbf{u}_1(\cdot)$ and $\mathbf{u}_2(\cdot):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},$

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{v}&=\int_0^3\Big[f_1(t)\mathbf{B}_1
+f_2(t)\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}_1\Big]\mathbf{u}_1(t)\mathrm{d}t
+\int_{0}^{2}\Big[f_3(t)\mathbf{B}_2+f_4(t)\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}_2\Big]\mathbf{u}_2(t)\mathrm{d}t\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray*}
Then can we say that, $\mathbf{v}\in Range \hspace{0.1 cm} space(\mathbf{B}_1|\mathbf{AB}_1|\mathbf{B}_2|\mathbf{AB}_2)?$

Note that here $(\mathbf{B}_1|\mathbf{AB}_1|\mathbf{B}_2|\mathbf{AB}_2):\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is an augumented linear operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all $$(\mathbf{B}_1|\mathbf{AB}_1|\mathbf{B}_2|\mathbf{AB}_2)\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\\c_4\end{bmatrix} = c_1 \mathbf{B}_1 + c_2 \mathbf{AB}_2 + c_3\mathbf{B}_2 + c_4\mathbf{AB}_2$$

Hence your range space is just $\operatorname{Span}\{\mathbf{B}_1, \mathbf{B}_2, \mathbf{AB}_1, \mathbf{AB}_2\}$. This is true no matter what the dimension the vectors $\mathbf{B}_1, \mathbf{B}_2$ are.

In the particular case when the $\mathbf{B}_i$ are 2-dimensional, you are talking about the span of four vectors in a 2-dimensional space. Therefore unless all four are multiples of the same vector, they span all of $\Bbb R^2$, so *any* vector $\mathbf{v}$ would be in their span.

But in this case, we can be sure $\mathbf v$ is in the span even when the four vectors are multiples, or the space is of dimension $> 2$:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{v}&=\int_0^3\Big[f_1(t)\mathbf{B}_1
+f_2(t)\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}_1\Big]u_1(t)\mathrm{d}t
+\int_{0}^{2}\Big[f_3(t)\mathbf{B}_2+f_4(t)\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}_2\Big]u_2(t)\mathrm{d}t\\&=\left(\int_0^3f_1(t)u_1(t)\mathrm{d}t\right)\mathbf{B}_1+\left(\int_0^3f_2(t)u_1(t)\mathrm{d}t\right)\mathbf{AB}_1\\&\quad +\left(\int_0^2f_3(t)u_2(t)\mathrm{d}t\right)\mathbf{B}_2+\left(\int_0^2f_4(t)u_2(t)\mathrm{d}t\right)\mathbf{AB}_2\end{align}$$

Comment: Dear Paul, whether the answer is still yes if $\mathbf{B}_1$ and $\mathbf{B}_2$ are $3\times 2$ matrices, $\mathbf{A}$ is $3\times 3$ matrix and $\mathbf{u}_1(t)$ and $\mathbf{u}_2(t)$ are $2\times 1$ matrices whose entries as continuous functions?

Comment: In that case, it is still likely that the span will be all of $\Bbb R^3$, but it is no longer guaranteed. Since the $\mathbf u_i$ are now vectors instead of scalars, they become part of the vector side that must be shown to be linearly independent, rather than the scalar side about which nothing needs to be proved. For some choices of the $f_i$ and $\mathbf u_i$, all four of the integrations will turn out to be multiples of the same vector. If $\mathbf A$ is also a multiple of $I$, then you will have at most two independent vectors in a 3-dimensional space.

Comment: But in any case the vector $\mathbf{v}$ always belongs to the range space of augmented matrix right?

Comment: Yes, it will be. Though now the augmented matrix is from $\Bbb R^8 \to \Bbb R^3$